# Восстановление файлов Linux или добавка для поиска файлов .class в scalpel

Tags: java, debian

Всем привет!2 дня назад случайно удалив всё содержимое папки root (а именно 2 папки в которых было около 40 файлов с расширением .class - скомпилированная java) и с ужасом понял что бэкапов нету, в интернете нашёл утилиту scalpel, но к сожалению она не ищет такие файлы, подскажите пожалуйста что нужно дописать в /etc/scalpel/scalpel.conf чтобы искались файлы .class

Выполнив команду mount я получил следующее

```
/dev/md2 on / type ext4 (rw,grpquota,usrquota)tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)/dev/md1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
```

После чего я выполнил команду

```
scalpel /dev/md2 -o output7
```

Спустя 4 часа в папке /root/output7 создалась туча папок с названиями java-цифра-цифра и файлов с расширением java одинакового размера и с непонятным содержимым. Отчаявшись я решил написать тут надеясь на хоть какую-то подсказку что дальше делать.

Команда **lsb_release -a** возвращает:

```
No LSB modules are available.Distributor ID: DebianDescription:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)Release:        6.0.7Codename:       squeeze
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Re-post: "Для Linux есть замечательная утилита, которая не раз меня спасала. Зовется testdisk, в ее составе есть также Photoreg. Находится в стандартных дистрибутивных пакетах, как правило.

Запускается из терминала, дальше интуитивно понятно..."

Не вижу причин для изобретения велосипеда, используйте проверенные средства!